# CDO tranche Pricing : Default probability

Tags: cdo

I'm trying to compute the price of a CDO at any time, using the *one factor gaussian copula* and *the Large Homogenous Portfolio Approximation*. You can find the CDO pricing formula in M. Neugebauer (2007): A comprehensive Analysis of Advanced Pricing Models for Collateralised Debt Obligations
 [here](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/legacy/12804/A%20comprehensive%20analysis%20of%20advanced%20pricing%20models%20for%20collateralised%20debt%20obligations.pdf).

As you can see in the formula $(2.13)$ page 9, the only difficulty is the computation of the expected tranche loss $ELT(t)$, but you can find a closed form (thanks to the one factor gaussian copula model and the large homogenous approximation), it is written in page 16 (equation $(2.37)$). We can see that $ELT(t)$ depends on the default probability of the reference name $P(\tau \le t)$, with $\tau$ being the default time of the reference name. If we assume that $\tau$ has an exponential distribution with hazard rate function $\lambda(t)$, then $P(\tau \le t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda (t)*t}$.

My question is : how do you calibrate $\lambda (t)$ ? I know that for CDSs, we have that $\lambda  \simeq \frac{s_0}{1-RR}$ with $s_0$ the *contractual spread*, and $RR$ the *recovery rate* (and at time $t$, you have $\lambda_t = s_t / 1-RR$ with $s_t$ the *market spread* at time $t$). How does it work in our case? Thank you.

Adam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems like a duplicate of your own question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/cds-mark-to-market.

Comment: This is different in that case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotes, on the market, usually for the 6m, 1y, 2y, 3y, 4y, 5y, 7y, 10y, 15y, 20y, 30y tenors, of quoted spreads / upfront that allow for backing out $\lambda$, provided you have a model on $\lambda$, like the Standard (ISDA/JPM) model. As far as I remember there is an open gamma paper on this question.